# Equivalent condition for tightness of probability measures on a Banach space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, banach-spaces, compactness, weak-convergence

Let $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space and $\mathcal M_1(E)$ denote the set of probability measures on $\mathcal B(E)$. Remember that $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathcal M_1(E)$ is called *tight* if $$\forall\varepsilon>0:\exists K\subseteq E\text{ compact}:\sup_{\mu\in\mathcal F}\mu(K^c)<\varepsilon\tag1.$$

> How can we show that $\mathcal F$ is tight if and only if for all $\varphi\in E'$, the family $\left\{\mu\circ\varphi^{-1}:\mu\in\mathcal F\right\}$ is tight and for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is a finite-dimensional subspace $L$ of $E$ with $$\inf_{\mu\in\mathcal F}\mu\left(N_\varepsilon(L)\right)>1-\varepsilon\tag2,$$ where $$N_\varepsilon(L):=\bigcup_{x\in L}B_\varepsilon(x)$$ and $B_\varepsilon(x)$ denotes the open ball with radius $\varepsilon$ around $x$ for $x\in E$?

The claim is made in Example 2.3.2 of [Bogachev's Weak Convergence of Measures](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/surv-234). He claims that the equivalence follows from the following fact:

> **Lemma**: Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space. Then $\mathcal H\subseteq\mathcal M_1(X)$ is tight if and only if $$\forall\varepsilon>0:\forall\delta>0:\exists U\in\mathcal U_\delta(E):\sup_{\mu\in\mathcal F}\mu(U^c)<\varepsilon\tag3$$, where $$\mathcal U_\delta(B):=\left\{\bigcup_{i=1}^kB_\delta(x_i):k\in\mathbb N\text{ and }x_1,\ldots,x_k\in B\right\}$$ for $B\subseteq E$.

The lemma is really easy to prove, since the completeness assumption ensures that every totally bounded set is relatively compact.

However, it's absolutely not clear to me how we can prove the desired claim. It's not even clear to me in which direction the lemma should be used.

Clearly, if $L$ is a finite-dimensional subspace of $E$, then $L=\operatorname{span}\left\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\right\}$ for some $x_1,\ldots,x_k\in E$ and $k:=\dim L$. We somehow need to use this ...

Answer (score 1):

Let's prove the reverse implication (the forward one is easier -- tightness follows from the fact that for any $\ell \in E'$ and any compact $K \in E$, $l(K)$ is compact; the other condition follows from the fact that any compact subset of $E$ is in a finite union of balls of radius $\epsilon$).

Let $\epsilon,\delta > 0$. We know that for any $0 < \eta < min(\epsilon,\delta)$, there is a finite-dimensional subspace $L$ with dimension $d$ (depending on $\eta$) such that for any $\mu \in \mathcal{F}$ (this is always the quantification on $\mu$, ie $\mu$ is always any element in $\mathcal{F}$ and nothing depends on $\mu$), $\mu(N_{\eta}(L)) \geq 1-\eta$.

(We specify $\eta$ later without circular dependence).

Let $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_d \in E'$ be such that they generate $L'$. We know that there is some $K > 0$ such that $\mu(\{|\phi_i| \geq K\}) \leq \frac{\eta}{d}$. Let now $N^L$ be the following seminorm on $E$: $N^L(x) = \|(\phi_i(x))_{1 \leq i \leq d}\|_{\infty}$. $N^L$ generates the topology of $L$ and we know that $\mu(E \backslash B_{N^L}(0,K)) \leq \eta$.

It follows that $\mu(N_{\eta}(L) \cap B_{N^L}(0,K)) \geq 1-2\eta$. In particular, if $2\eta < \delta$, then $N_{\eta}(L) \cap B_{N^L}(0,K)$ can be covered by finitely many balls with center in $L$ with radius $\delta$ (consider a covering of $L \cap B_{N^L}(0,K)$ with balls of radius $\delta/2$, and consider the balls with the same centers but radius $\delta$ instead).

So we have a finite reunion $U$ of balls of radius $\delta$ such that $\mu(U^c) \leq 2\eta$. So if we choose $\eta < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $\eta < \frac{\delta}{2}$, we are done, and the criterion from the lemma applies.